# codeigniter get postgres fieldtypes of recent query

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter

I am using php with codeigniter.
I like to run a sql query on my postgres db and I am interested not only in the result but in the field types as well.

There is the php function:
pg_field_type ( resource $result , int $field_number )

that should return the information I need, but I wonder if there is a way to use it with codeigniter db class?

**Versions**

postgres: 9.4
codeigniter: 3.1.10

**Example**

```
$res = $this->db->query("select * from foobar);
```

returns me an result object like this:

```
CI_DB_postgre_result Object
(
[conn_id] => Resource id #2
[result_id] => Resource id #5
[result_array] => Array
    (
    )

[result_object] => Array
    (
    )

[custom_result_object] => Array
    (
    )

[current_row] => 0
[num_rows] => 
[row_data] => 
)
```

It its visual that Resource id #5 would be my resource but how to access it?

best,

d.

Answer (score 0):

```
$res = $this->db->query("select * from foobar);
$data =  $res->result();
print_r( $data ) // will print all the rows

//return $data // will return data to the controller
```

Comment: yeah, I know how to retreve the query results. But as mentioned in my question, I am interested in the field types (e.g. text, varchar, timestamp ...). Best.